# PHP not loading xdebug when started from Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

Hei helping people!

Some while ago I installed xdebug and had some trouble getting it to work — but I did.

Now I tried starting debugging again, but it wouldn't work.

If I call `php -m` or `phpinfo()` through the browser, it tells me that xdebug is loaded.

But when I start phpinfo() as phpscript from Eclipse, it doesn't load.

Also adding a line like `xdebug_break()` it'll tell me

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function xdebug_break() in /home/andy/public_html/phpDebugTest/console.php on line 3

I learned that php is called from Eclipse with different include-paths, but I added the same as from php.ini to the project.

Thanks a lot for helping out!