# PHP in Eclipse not loading Xdebug

Tags: php, eclipse, macos, command-line-interface, xdebug

I'm running Eclipse Mars on OSX, and was using the default PHP 5.5.x in `/usr/bin/php`. I upgraded to PHP 7.1, installed in `/usr/local/php5`.

Now, CLI debugging no longer works in Eclipse. When I run `phpinfo()` as a CLI application from inside Eclipse, it does not show Xdebug being loaded.  The Xdebug ini file is in `/usr/local/php5/php.d`

If I look in the `phpinfo()` output, I see:

```
'--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php5/php.d'
```

However it also says:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php5/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /private/var/folders/vj/rwjyy7xd08z94cblq7yhnb2w0000gn/T/zend_debug/session6507081221226503822.tmp/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
```

Which explains why Xdebug isn't being loaded. What is the `/private/var/folders...`  ini file and where is being told to load that from?

Side note: If I run `phpinfo()` from Eclipse as a web application, it loads Xdebug just fine and debug works just fine.

My question is why isn't PHP within Eclipse scanning `/usr/local/php5/php.d` and loading those ini files. How do I make it do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer on another thread that works:
[PHP not loading xdebug when started from Eclipse PDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887062/php-not-loading-xdebug-when-started-from-eclipse-pdt?rq=1)

Short answer:  for some reason, Eclipse starts php with the "-n" option, which stops loading of ini files.  Workaround, found here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339547

is to create a script as below that strips the "-n" parameter and runs php.  I named it php_eclipse_start.  Then set that script as the php executable in Eclipse.  This worked.  Here's the script:

#!/bin/sh

if [ $1 = "-n" ]; then

shift;

fi

/usr/local/php5/bin/php $*